# MySQL stored procedure return null

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure with out parameter (code):

```
SELECT code = RIGHT(CONCAT(REPEAT(0, 6), (SELECT MAX(CONVERT(code, int)) + 1 FROM enterprises)), 6)
```

If I exec it, return null value, but if I execute the single query, it works right. Why?

Comment: Can you show full procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename parameter, try to write something like this (parameter name `code_param`) -

```
SELECT
  RIGHT(CONCAT(REPEAT(0, 6), (SELECT MAX(CONVERT(code, int)) + 1 FROM enterprises)), 6)
INTO code_param;
```